# Make a popup list with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

What I want to do:

1. Make a button.
2. If you hover over it, a toplevel appears, and if you remove the cursor, the toplevel disappears.
3. If you move the cursor from the button to this toplevel, it doesn't(!) disappear, and if you move cursor somewhere else, it finally disappears.

To do so I created 2 classes (button and toplevel). I tried binding **Enter** and **Leave** to both of them but this leads to 2 problems:

1. If you move cursor from the button, the toplevel should get destroyed, but it's created with func_1 and is destroyed with func_2 which leads to an error.
2. To make moving cursor from button to toplevel safe I tried to remove the *button's* **Leave** bind and then add it back toplevel's **Leave** bind but it only leads to more problems.

This is what I have now:

```
import tkinter as tk


class PopupButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Button.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.bind("<Enter>", self.button_enter)
        self.bind("<Leave>", self.button_leave)

    def button_enter(self, event):
        self.configure(bg="grey")
        toplevel = Popup(root, bg="lightblue")
        toplevel.overrideredirect(1)

        x = root.winfo_x()
        y = root.winfo_y()
        toplevel.geometry("100x100+{}+{}".format(x+160, y+485))

    def button_leave(self, event):
        self.configure(bg="black")
        pass
        # problem here


class Popup(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.bind("<Enter>", self.toplevel_enter)
        self.bind("<Leave>", self.toplevel_leave)

    def toplevel_enter(self, event):
        pass
        # problem here

    def toplevel_leave(self, event):
        self.destroy()


root = tk.Tk()
root.configure(bg="white")
root.geometry("400x600")

button = PopupButton(root, text="Hover over me", font="courier 20", bg="black", fg="white")
button.pack(side="bottom")

root.mainloop()
```

This is the most I could do. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the code given in the question and I modified the `button_leave` method so that when the cursor leaves the button, the toplevel is destroyed only if the cursor is not over it (I used the `winfo_containing` method to know in which widget the cursor is). I also deleted the `toplevel_enter` method because it was not needed here.

```
import tkinter as tk

class PopupButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Button.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.bind("<Enter>", self.button_enter)
        self.bind("<Leave>", self.button_leave)

    def button_enter(self, event):
        self.configure(bg="grey")
        self.toplevel = Popup(root, bg="lightblue")
        self.toplevel.overrideredirect(1)

        # the root window is the button master
        x = self.master.winfo_x()
        y = self.master.winfo_y()
        self.toplevel.geometry("100x100+{}+{}".format(x+160, y+485))

    def button_leave(self, event):
        self.configure(bg="black")
        # if the pointer is not in the toplevel -> destroy the toplevel
        if self.winfo_containing(*self.winfo_pointerxy()) != self.toplevel:
            self.toplevel.destroy()


class Popup(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        # destroy toplevel when the pointer leaves it
        self.bind("<Leave>", self.toplevel_leave)

    def toplevel_leave(self, event):
        self.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()
root.configure(bg="white")
root.geometry("400x600")

button = PopupButton(root, text="Hover over me", font="courier 20", bg="black", fg="white")
button.pack(side="bottom")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your answer would be better if you included at least a little bit of an explanation of what you did. Otherwise we're forced to read the code and compare it line-by-line to the original to see what you changed.